# How can I incorporate a wildcard or regex into a Selenium test?

Tags: javascript, selenium, url, automation

I have a pretty simple Nightwatch test written in javascript and part of it is to verify that the URL of the page is correct. The URL contains a random string of numbers each time the page is resubmitted, this string of numbers will change. The rest of the URL is static and already accounted for.

I have been searching and reading and still have not found a working solution, but I can't imagine its all that rare or difficult of a problem to overcome. I'm pretty brand new at javascript so I may be overlooking something simple, but I could really use some help.

Comment: How would you `verify that the URL of the page is correct` unless you know in advance the _random string of numbers each time the page is resubmitted_?

Comment: That's the question DebanjanB, which is why I am asking about using a regex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: _The URL contains a random string of numbers_ are you looking for a regex or you already have the regex and you want to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to verify the URL pattern. Use `\d+` to match any number of digits.

For example if URL you're trying to match is `www.example.com/path/123` where `123` is dynamic and can change you can use the following regex to test it.

```
var url = "www.example.com/path/123";
var regex = /www\.example\.com\/path\/\d+/;
regex.test(url)
```

Here `regex.test(url)` will return `true` for URL shown in example and also for URL's like `www.example.com/path/111` or `www.example.com/path/4` etc.

You can further improve the regex to ensure that it start with `www` by using `^` at the beginning of the regex like `/^www\.example\.com\/path\/\d+/`

Read more on regular expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

**EDIT:**

Here is a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thanthu/s0np9acr/20/) I just wrote with the same code, that read's URL given in `input` field and test's its pattern with regex and shows `alert` with `true` or `false` based on result.

In your case I am guessing you are using selenium to read the current URL instead of reading it from an `input`. And you'll have to change the regex according to URL you are testing.

You can provide the URL you are testing in the `input` field and modify regex in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thanthu/s0np9acr/20/) for testing.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Are you able to help me understand how to use that regex within javascript? For instance, I have 

let regex = \/www\.example\.com\/path\/\d+\/;

and I'm using it here: 

on.page().pageObject(regex.test(url + regex));

but that obviously isn't working. I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax for using the regex.  :(

Comment: Ya I can take a look. Can you share the snippet of you code and the actual URL you are trying to match, specifying which are the numbers that change. So what you basically have to do is get the value of URL you want to test in a variable and modify the regex I shared according to the URL

Comment: I've edited the answer with a link to a JSFiddle that you can use.